# Is it possible to publicly auto-upload pictures with Google?

Tags: google-plus, google-photos, google-plus-photos, android

The photos I take with my Android phone are automatically uploaded by Google Photos to Google.

Is it possible to set this upload up so that **all** the uploaded photos **automatically** are made public? Currently I can share a photo from this stream (or make an album) and explicitly set it to "Public" so that it is available on my Google+ profile, but I did not find a way to set that as a default.

*Note: I am of course aware of how horrendous this idea is (and I would not be surprised if this is something which is not possible to set up) - I need to understand the feasibility aspect.*

Comment: I doubt that Google would let you do such a thing; they're protecting you from yourself. That said, it shouldn't be too difficult to create an [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com) recipe that will publish any photo taken on your phone to a service designed to be for public photos, such as Flickr or even Tumblr.

Answer (score -3):

Normally it's doable, but google does not offer this option thanks to global security.
https://www.google.com/intl/fr/policies/privacy/

Comment: Can you include the relevant passages and provide an English translation, please?  Otherwise, the link is not much use to anyone.